# Why is ExoPlayer initial load time of video is more than 5 seconds?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

ExoPlayer's initial load time is more than 5 seconds even after using DefaultLoadControl().

```
private fun initializePlayer() {
    if (player == null) {
        trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()
        loadControl = DefaultLoadControl(
                DefaultAllocator(true, 1024),
                1000, // this is it!
                2000,
                1500,
                3000,
                1024,
                true
        )
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                trackSelector,
                loadControl)
        player!!.addListener(componentListener)
        player!!.addVideoDebugListener(componentListener)
        player!!.addAudioDebugListener(componentListener)
        video_view.setPlayer(player)
        player!!.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady)
        player!!.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
        val uri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.media_url_mp4))
        val mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri)
        val mergerMediaSource = MergingMediaSource(mediaSource, buildSubtitleSource(getString(R.string.media_url_subtitle)))
        player!!.prepare(mergerMediaSource, true, false)
    }
}
```

The video I tried to load is [this](http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4)

Comment: Did you find a way to reduce the initial load time?

Answer (score 1):

Problem here seems like calling

```
player!!.prepare(mergerMediaSource, true, false)
```

after

```
player!!.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
```

The second parameter of `player.prepare()` is resetPosition which is true by default. That's why, the position is reset to the default.

Try to seek after prepare or pass false to resetPosition

Comment: Tried the above solution but still found no luck. It still takes around 5 seconds to load the video.